# Using sql to find which lookup tables are linked to table fields?

Tags: sql, oracle, hyperlink, key

I have a table Entity. This table references various look up tables. For example the field 'ethnicity_code' in the entity table references a look up table called 'lkp_race'. Now it is not too difficult to figure out that race and ethnicity are connected, but in toher instances the connection is not so clear. I would like to be able to know which of the 'lkp_' tables are referenced from other tables like entity. Is there a way to use Oracle pl sql to write a query to say something like the following:

If tablename LIKE 'lkp_%' then what are the tables that link to these tables and on what fields are they linked by?

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can query `USER_CONSTRAINTS` to get foreign-key references. Look for constraints of type "R" (referential):

```
SELECT R_Constraint_Name
FROM User_Constraints
WHERE Table_Name = 'ENTITY'
  AND Constraint_Type = 'R'
```

That will give you a list of primary keys from the tables that your `ENTITY` table references. To get the referenced table name is a bit confusing: you need to self-join to the `USER_CONSTRAINTS` table:

```
SELECT target.Table_Name
FROM User_Constraints src
JOIN User_Constraints target ON src.R_Constraint_Name = target.Constraint_Name
WHERE src.Table_Name = 'ENTITY'
  AND src.Constraint_Type = 'R'
```

To list the columns which are referenced in the other table, use the `User_Cons_Columns` view:

```
SELECT cols.Table_Name, cols.Column_Name
FROM User_Constraints src
JOIN User_Cons_Columns cols ON src.R_Constraint_Name = cols.Constraint_Name
WHERE src.Table_Name = 'ENTITY'
  AND src.Constraint_Type = 'R'
ORDER BY src.Table_Name, cols.Position
```

Comment: If I try the following code you have suggested: 

>SELECT R_Constraint_Name
>FROM User_Constraints
>WHERE Table_Name = 'ENTITY'
>  AND Constraint_Type = 'R'

The results are blank with just the column heading R_CONTSRAINT_NAME. But this table definitely has fields that link to other tables. Any idea why the results are blank?

Comment: The query should find references that go from `ENTITY` to another table. Does your `ENTITY` table have actual foreign key references to other tables? Also, are you logged on as the table owner?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
CREATE TABLE entity(
  somefield varchar2(100),
  ethnicity_code number
);

CREATE TABLE lkp_race(
  code number primary key,
  some_other_field varchar2( 100)
);

ALTER TABLE entity ADD CONSTRAINT eth_code_fk
   FOREIGN KEY ( ethnicity_code ) REFERENCES lkp_race( code );

  SELECT x1.table_name,
          col1.column_name,
          x2.table_name referenced_table_name,
          col2.column_name referenced_column_name
   FROM  all_constraints x1
   JOIN all_constraints x2
   ON x1.constraint_name = x2.r_constraint_name
   JOIN all_cons_columns col1
   ON x1.constraint_name = col1.constraint_name 
      AND x1.table_name = col1.table_name
   JOIN all_cons_columns col2
   ON x2.constraint_name = col2.constraint_name 
      AND x2.table_name = col2.table_name
   WHERE x1.owner = 'TEST' 
     AND x1.table_name LIKE 'LKP%'
   ORDER BY x1.owner, x1.table_name, col1.position,
            x2.owner, x2.table_name, col2.position;
```

Result:

```
TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
---------- ----------- --------------------- ----------------------
LKP_RACE   CODE        ENTITY                ETHNICITY_CODE
```

Comment: Same issue. I can see the column names but not the data. Not sure why. perhaps my user access does not allow for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT f.name AS ForeignKey,
SCHEMA_NAME(f.SCHEMA_ID) SchemaName,
OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS TableName,
COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,fc.parent_column_id) AS ColumnName,
SCHEMA_NAME(o.SCHEMA_ID) ReferenceSchemaName,
OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) AS ReferenceTableName,
COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id,fc.referenced_column_id) AS ReferenceColumnName
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON o.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id
order by 1;
```